# .NET Core 6 MVC AddRazorRuntimeCompilation breaks Global Usings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

When using the following statement:

```
var builder = services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Global usings do not work at all within MVC views. Is this a known issue? Is there some other configuration required to get runtime compilation and global usings at the same time?

Comment: Hi, It works fine and are you sure you share the correct code? The correct code in .net 6 should be: `var builder =WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

Comment: @Rena I can confirm that adding `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` to my previously working code breaks global usings.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue in .net 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27390). It has been targeted for .net 7, but no official word on if it will be included or not. [Documentation was updated 2022/12/16](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/pull/27859/files/b630c78f48c2159ac224cdfabb29ba359e907b2e) to address the problem in .net 6.